# Navigable menus with keyboard in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table in HTML with twitter bootstraps.

When I click on the table javascript get an id and fills a Modal with information. Something like this:

```
$('.table > tbody > tr').click(function() {
   //lots of things happens
});
```

---

```
 <div class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
               <!-- lots of information loaded with AJAX --->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This works fine, however I want to be able not only to click, but to navigate with buttons (pressing down key would go down and pressing up key would a row up).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would capture the key inputs on the whole document and modify what you need at will, here is a basic template for the arrow keys. If you need other keys here is a useful site to get them http://keycode.info/

```
document.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {

    e = e || window.event;

    if (e.keyCode == '38') {
        // up arrow
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
        // down arrow
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
       // left arrow
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
       // right arrow
    }

}
```

Comment: `e.keyCode` is a `number`, not a `string`, so it would probably be better to compare it as `e.keyCode === 38`. Anyway, `e.keyCode` is deprecated. `e.key` or `e.code` should be used instead, which also makes the code easier to understand. Just keep in mind some old browsers used non-standard codes, so left is usually `'LeftArrow'` and right is `'RightArrow'`, but on IE it's just `'Left'` and `'Right'` instead. Also, take a look at https://keyjs.dev. I will add information about these kinds of cross-browser incompatibilities soon! 

Answer (score 3):

First you need to wrap your code with function and call it from your click handler:

```
var $table = $('.table'),
    $tableRows = $table.find('tbody > tr');

$tableRows.click(function() {
    rowToModal($(this));
});

function rowToModal($row) {
    $tableRows.removeClass('active-row');
    $row.addClass('active-row');

    //lots of things happens
}
```

Then, you can make handler for "keydown" event:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (/*check if modal is currently open*/ ) {
        var $currentRow = $($table.find('.active-row')),
            $nextRow;

        if (e.key == 'ArrowDown') {
            $nextRow = $currentRow.next();
        } else if (e.key == 'ArrowUp') {
            $nextRow = $currentRow.prev();
        }

        if ($nextRow && $nextRow.length) {
            rowToModal($nextRow );
        }
    }
});
```